# Why do I have no option to set up GA4 Configuration in Tag Manager?

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have my GA4 property and my Tag Manager, but in tags there is no option to connect the two. The only GA4 option I have is "Google Analytics: GA4 Event"

I was expecting to have the option to select "Google Analytics: GA4 Configuration"

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Google messed up. Wait for them to fix it or use the Legacy option.

This is what you used to see in your tag types list:

[image]

Now it's under Legacy tags and Google tells you to use the new Google Tag:

[image]

However, google forgot to add the actual Google Tag to the list of options, so the info there is just misleading. Moreover, if you click  `Learn more`, you will get to Google's SSO page:

[image]

Which only indicates that they published a lower environment link to production.

Neat, eh? Looks like the quality of Google's devs doesn't go up. Seems like QA is overrated. Let's see how long it stays there. I'm updating this on the 2023-09-07. 2023-09-11: In the evening, they changed the learn more link. Great job Google, but still no tag type indicated in the learn more page. Finally, the missing tag type was added on 2023-09-19. Bravo GTM, only 12 days for a hotfix. Now it looks like this: [image]

Comment: It is a web container, and searching only brings up the GA4 Event tag.

Comment: can you please make a screenshot?

Comment: Looks like they're rolling out a new tag type to replace the GA4 Configuration. And they're probably doing a lame A/B test there to measure their half-baked change. See if you have "Google tags" type. That's supposed to be the upgraded GA4 config type.

Comment: You're right. I used 'google tags' and it worked. Thank you

Comment: I'm happy that google tags appears for you, it's still not available for me though, heh. Probably a fresh deployment not yet cascaded to the whole CDN or something.

Answer (score 0):

It is no longer available, instead you can click 'Google Analytics' and Google Tag

[image: Google Tag]

and paste your Analytics code starts with G- .

Every time you create a new event you will have to enter your G- code again and again. You can create a user defined variable under 'constant' to not enter your G- code again every time, but not a big difference to be honest.